# Вычитание в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В JS:

```
0.3 - 0.95 = -0.6499999999999999
```

Как с этим бороться не используя округления? (Пишу калькулятор, поэтому везде округления не натыкаю.)

Answer (score 3):

Не используя округления — никак. Или ведите все вычисления в целых числах (вот вам библиотечка для примера, [BigInt.js](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js)), или осознайте, что в вычислениях с плавающей точкой (например, на стандарте [IEEE 754](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4610935)) потеря точности неизбежна.

Comment: Не обязательно. Вот сам нашел .toFixed(x), так что сторонние либы не обязательно - ушел тестить

Comment: `toFixed` — ну так это и есть округление. А я предлагал либу для длинных целых.